# How should I use the lock/unlock mutex?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, pthreads, mutex

Implement a program that creates two threads. The threads will print their ID (pthread_self) 10 times and then stop. Insure that the printed IDs alternate always (ie A, B, A, B, ...)

The question is: where should I put the lock and unlock mutex?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#define N 2 

pthread_mutex_t mtx; 

void* func (void* arg) { 
    int i=0; 
    int f=1;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++) { 
        printf("%d%s%d\n",f ,": ", (int)pthread_self()); 
        f++;  
    }
    return NULL; 
}

int main() { 
    int i; 
    pthread_t thr[N]; 
    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL); 

    for(i=0; i<N; i++) { 
        pthread_create(&thr[i], NULL, func, NULL); 
    } 

    for(i=0; i<N; i++) { 
        pthread_join(thr[i], NULL); 
    } 

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mtx);  
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a homework assignment that you should (try to) figure out by yourself?

Comment: What is the role of `f`? It is always one more than `i`.

Also, what is allowed to solve the problem? Can you only insert statements, or are other transformations allowed?